# Can I install manage package that contains Apex Class on essential edition ORG

Tags: apex, integration, licenses, editions

Is it possible to install a managed package containing Apex Class with REST Endpoint (public, hosted on salesforce Site.com ) in an Essential edition organization?

Basically what I am looking to do is to have My custom API endpoint, and 1 outgoing integration in my salesforce ORG, but in the beginning, I need to have only basic salesforce functionality with only a few users, later on, I plan to expand, but now I want to save costs.

My Idea is to install these Apex classes in the organization using the managed package I will prepare for myself using developer org.

Comment: I think you won't be able to - I think this ability is restricted to managed packages that are listed on the app exchange or that have at least successfully gone through security review.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Phil, [Apex Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_what_is_apex.htm) are only accessible in the Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, Developer, and Database.com Editions, and are not available in the Essential edition

If you are a salesforce partner, you can log into [Partner Portal](https://partners.salesforce.com/pdx/s/?language=en_US&redirected=RGSUDODQUL) to sign up for Professional/Enterprise Edition demo orgs that allows to installation of managed beta packages and uncertified apex.

Please note that these orgs should only be used for testing purposes and check benefits of using a partner demo org [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000391959&type=1).

Comment: How about apps from AppExchange that contain apex code? Can they be installed on Essentials edition? Any reference?